# Como deixar em formato moeda?

Tags: javascript

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Minha Vida</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var total1 = 0;
    var total2 = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table tbody tr').each(function() {

            total1 += parseFloat(this.children[3].innerHTML);
            total2 += parseFloat(this.children[4].innerHTML);

        });

        $('table tfoot td#1').text(total1);
        $('table tfoot td#2').text(total2);
    });


</script>
```

```
    <table id="sum_table" style="width:50%" align="center">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#FFFF00" class="header-table">
                <th>Corretora</th>
                <th>Ação</th>
                <th>Qtde</th>
                <th>Valor1</th>
                <th>Valor2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
                <td><img src="imagens/rico-corretora-logo.jpg" width="100" /></td>
                <td>ODPV3</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>2.000</td>
                <td>1.000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="imagens/rico-corretora-logo.jpg" width="100" /></td>
                <td>ODPV3</td>
                <td>100,00</td>
                <td>2.000,00</td>
                <td>500,00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="imagens/rico-corretora-logo.jpg" width="100" /></td>
                <td>WEGE3</td>
                <td>100,00</td>
                <td>1.800,00</td>
                <td>500,00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=3>Total Investido</th>
                <td id="1"></td>
                <td id="2"></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode formatar números em moedas utilizando uma instância da classe [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) que permite a formatação personalizável de número sensível a linguagem.

Para aplicar o formato a um objeto Number, BigInt ou String use o método [`Intl.NumberFormat.format()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/format)

```js
//Declara e inicie uma instância de Intl.NumberFormat
const fmt = new Intl.NumberFormat(
  'pt-BR',                         //Configura localização como português do Brasil.
  {
    style: 'currency',             //Configura o estilo de formatação como moeda.
    currency: 'BRL'                //Configura a moeda como Real Brasileiro.
  }
)

$(document).ready(function() {
  let total1 = 0, total2 = 0;                      //Traz a declaração dos totais para dentro do escopo do evento ready.
  $('#sum_table tbody tr').each(function() {
    total1 += Number($("td:eq(0)", this).text());  //Faz alguns ajustes para facilitar a leitura do código fonte.
    total2 += Number($("td:eq(1)", this).text());  //Faz alguns ajustes para facilitar a leitura do código fonte.
  });
  //Aplica a formatação. 
  $('#sum_table tfoot td#1').text( fmt.format(total1) );
  $('#sum_table tfoot td#2').text( fmt.format(total2) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="sum_table">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFF00">
      <th>Valor1</th>
      <th>Valor2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2.700</td>
      <td>1.530</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=3>Total Formatado</th>
      <td id="1"></td>
      <td id="2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Para mais informações consulte [documentação da API de Internacionalização](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

Answer (score -5):

Basta usar a função toFixed() com duas casa decimais.

```
$('table tfoot td#1').text(total1.toFixed(2));
$('table tfoot td#2').text(total2.toFixed(2));
```